# How to Switch to Unity 3d

Tags: 12.04, unity

My computer used to run Unity 3d (in Ubuntu 12.04), but when I started it up today, it was in Unity 2d.  I was messing with some Ubuntu One packages recently, but I don't think that I did anything with graphics at all.

I tried selecting Ubuntu (rather than Unity 2d) at the login screen, and that didn't change anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide details on graphics chip/card.

Comment: In the intervening year, probably when I installed 12.10, the problem fixed itself.  Not sure what the fix or problem was.